# Need Fast Help on Kinetic Energy of Curve

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, curves

I posted about this problem a few days ago but it didn't seem to get too much play so I'm going to re-write it and hopefully get some assistance.

Consider the Kinetic Energy Functional...

E($\gamma$) = $\frac 12\int_I ||\gamma^{'}(t)||^{2}dt$

for the curve $\gamma: I \to R^{n}$

**i**) Show this functional is not Parameterization Invariant

**ii**)  Show that γ is a critical point of E under compactly supported variations
$γ_s$ if and only if $\gamma^{''}$ = 0, i.e., γ(t) = $x_0$ + tv is a constant speed straight
line (notice, no assumptions on the regularity of the curve is needed).

**iii**) Find the Minima of E

My thoughts...

**i**) So for this I was going to basically argue that one could calculate E in a particular parameterization and then reparameterize by arc length and thus since ||$\gamma^{'}||$ = 1 for Arc-Length parameterized curves I would say that you can go from any arbitrary parameterization (then probably show an E that doesn't equal 1 -- i.e., parameterize like x(t) = a*cos(t) and y(t) = b*cos(t)) to an arc length parameterization where E always equals t/2 when I runs from 0 to t.

**ii**) I just dont know how exactly do differentiate a functional and thus how to find the criitcal points of such a functional

**iii**) Again I just need assistance with differentiating and any other facets to finding the minima of a functional (if it's not in direct analogy with minima of functions)

Comment: Try google Euler-Lagrange equations. To differentiate the integrand, simply use Chain rule (:

Comment: Hey thanks I actually figured that out a few minutes ago (thank the lord for wikipedia) and was in the process of doing that. Just a quick question so my L (what's being differentiated in EL equations) is just the length squared of the curve (thus it involves the derivative of the curve) so if I differentiate the derivative of the curve with respect to its anti-derivative (just the curve, gamma) I should get zero correct?

Comment: Also, any guidance on how to determine if the critical point is a minima?

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you said on the first comment. I might be wrong but if the second variation of your functional is positive-definite, then your critical point is a minima.

Comment: That's fine I'm currently following [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations ] under the _Variations and sufficient condition for a minimum_ tab.

I just did the J[x + h] - J[x] step and I'm just wondering is what I'm left with after I subtract J[x] from J[x + h] the first variation? And if it is how do I find the second variation?

Comment: No, you then need to divide by $h$ and take the limit as $h\longrightarrow 0$. They are ``really" just generalisation of derivatives in the classical sense. I don't really know how to compute the second variation, a quick google search should give you something useful (: I never compute the second variation myself in practice, once I know it's a critical point, I usually try to prove that it is a minimum using first principle, i.e. show that $J(u+v)\le J(u)$ for any admissible functions $v$. This approach is problem-dependent, it might be nontrivial to show this sometimes!

Comment: For (i): The curve $\gamma(t) = (t, 0)$ and $\gamma(t) = (t^2, 0)$, $t\in [0,1]$ has different energies.

Comment: Yeah I'm finding a bit of difficulty showing that $J(u + v) \leqslant J(u)$ Once I calculated it I found essentially that $J(u + v) - J(u) = 0.5 \int_{0}^{t} {v'^{2} + 2u'v'}dt \leqslant 0$ But I'm not exactly sure how to show that this quantity is less than or equal to zero or equivalently that J(u + v) is less than or equal to J(u).. any help?